# Resizing tmux isn't working while in AWS SSM. How to troubleshoot?

Tags: tmux

When starting an instance in AWS SSM, it seems like Tmux is not embracing the full window, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Usually this happens when there's another client attached to this session, but this is not the case for me right now. In fact, I just created a new session just for testing purposes, and it's this small.

If I back out of tmux, my bash terminal is actually filling the entire window.

I have tried setting the window size to aggressive with:

```
set-window-option -g aggressive-resize
```

but this doesn't seem to do anything.

Any other suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to just simply resize the physical terminal window manually. Apparently Tmux doesn't know about the current window size, so the minute I resized it manually, tmux adjusted itself.